# FitNesse playing with variables using basic operation

Tags: variables, fitnesse, operation

This is a very simple question, because I could create a method for do that but:

Could I do basic operations with a variable defined inside a **Dofixture** table?
Like:

Getting the var: `|OperationResult|<<MyVar|`

And then, use for example `Check|>>MyVar+1|`

I use `>>MyVar+1`, or for example  (`>>MyVar / >>OtherVar`)

Could I change if you are using SLiM or FitSharp plugin?

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the String variables even objects in a fitness variable and then passing that variable to another method call. You can even do more tricky things with splitting the object execution but I am not sure about other operations. 
This is are some examples of how I am using some variables in the fitness test pages:

Example 1:

this is how you get the value:

```
|$MyVar=|methodReturningMyVar|
```

this is how you can pass the value

```
|methodReceivingMyVarValue|$MyVar|
```

Example 2:

Splitting the execution of a script in 2 parts

```
|Scrip| MyScriptWithSplitedExecution|
|$MyScriptWithSplitedExecutionObject| get Instance |
|doFirstPartOfProcessing|

here you can do some other operations/tests

|Scrip|$MyScriptWithSplitedExecutionObject|
|doSecondPartOfProcessing|
```

For this to work you have to implement the getInstance method in your object and make it return a pointer to himself.

All this were tested with Slim, I don't know if are working with FitSharp.

Answer (score 0):

No, operations like this are not supported.